# The meaning of "view as"

Tags: meaning

I read the news and found a sentence that was not clear to me.

"Other companies are focusing on lawmakers they view as complicit in Trump's effort to disrupt the affirmation of Biden's election win."

1. Is "which or that" missing between lawmakers and they? Can I rewrite the above sentence to " lawmakers which they view as~"?
2. Is "view as" a phrase(verb function)? If so, how can the adjective(complicit) be there?

Comment: Yes, 'focusing on [those] lawmakers who they view as [being / having been] complicit ... in full. // 'He was complicit in the crime' uses the adjective 'complicit' with the adjective complement 'in the crime'; 'complicit in' is a colligation. 'He was regarded/seen/viewed/accepted as being [complicit in the crime] // 'He was suspected/cleared of being ...' // Different verbs take different prepositions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can add *which* or *that* after "lawmakers" (I would personally add ***whom*** in this context). The relative pronoun ***whom*** (or *which* or *that*) is not missing, it has just been elided.

> Other companies are focusing on lawmakers (***whom/which/that***) they view as complicit in
> Trump's effort to disrupt the affirmation of Biden's election win.

So the sentence is correct with or without it, just as when we say ***The people I know*** instead of ***The people whom/that I know***.

As for "view as", the phrase means ([WordHippo](https://www.wordhippo.com/what-is/another-word-for/view_as.html)):

> - To regard or view in a given way
> - To regard or consider in a specified way
> - To refer to or consider (someone or something) as being

It can be followed by a noun (phrase) or an adjective:

> Life on the set is pervaded by what the uninvolved might well ***view as*** (or ***consider***) ***superstition***. ("view as" + noun)
>
> Cronin and Magdalinski want an alternative to the current political process, ***which*** they ***view as unrepresentative*** of real-world needs. ("view as" + adjective)

In the last sentence I have underlined ***which***, because it relates to your first question about whether you can put in a relative pronoun or not.